# How show loading spinner in Jetpack Compose while Google Maps load?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

Following several tutorials on the internet, I have managed to paint a Google map in my application:

```
@Composable
fun MyMap(
    lat: Double,
    lon: Double
) {

    val mapView = rememberMapViewWithLifeCycle()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        AndroidView(
            { mapView }
        ) { mapView ->
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                val map = mapView.awaitMap()
                map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = false
                val destination = LatLng(lat, lon)
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(destination, 16f))
                val markerOptionsDestination = MarkerOptions()
                    .position(destination)
                map.addMarker(markerOptionsDestination)
                map.mapType = com.google.android.libraries.maps.GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberMapViewWithLifeCycle(): MapView {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val mapView = remember {
        MapView(context).apply {
            id = R.id.map_frame
        }
    }
    val lifeCycleObserver = rememberMapLifecycleObserver(mapView)
    val lifeCycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    DisposableEffect(lifeCycle) {
        lifeCycle.addObserver(lifeCycleObserver)
        onDispose {
            lifeCycle.removeObserver(lifeCycleObserver)
        }
    }

    return mapView
}

@Composable
fun rememberMapLifecycleObserver(mapView: MapView): LifecycleEventObserver =
    remember(mapView) {
        LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> mapView.onCreate(Bundle())
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> mapView.onStart()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> mapView.onResume()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> mapView.onPause()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> mapView.onStop()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> mapView.onDestroy()
                else -> throw IllegalStateException()
            }
        }
    }
```

I load this composable from another composable where I have more elements, like texts and so on:

```
@Composable
fun MyMain() {
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .size(300.dp)
) {
    MyMap(lat, lon)
}
}
```

The map takes time to load, not long, maybe 1 second or less. But I would like the MyMain composable instead of being empty box (the box that contains the map) that second, to show a loading spinner. How could I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do something like this: 
If the map isn't actually fully loaded after mapView.awaitMap() try replacing the line with a delay(1000). (or longer than 1000 ms)

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyMap(
    lat: Double,
    lon: Double,
) {
    val mapView = rememberMapViewWithLifeCycle()

    var isMapLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    LaunchedEffect(mapView) {
        mapView.awaitMap()
        isMapLoading = false
    }

    Box {
        AndroidView(
            { mapView }
        ) { mapView ->
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                val map = mapView.awaitMap()
                map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = false
                val destination = LatLng(lat, lon)
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(destination, 16f))
                val markerOptionsDestination = MarkerOptions()
                    .position(destination)
                map.addMarker(markerOptionsDestination)
                map.mapType = com.google.android.libraries.maps.GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
            }
        }
        if (isMapLoading) {
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .matchParentSize()
                    .background(Color.White)
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
inline fun DrawGoogleMap(
    positionState: CameraPositionState, crossinline onGoogleMapDrawn: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val permissionState = getPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

    var isMapLoaded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        GoogleMap(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            uiSettings = MapUiSettings(
                tiltGesturesEnabled = true,
                myLocationButtonEnabled = true,
                zoomControlsEnabled = true,
                scrollGesturesEnabled = true,
                scrollGesturesEnabledDuringRotateOrZoom = true
            ),
            cameraPositionState = positionState,
            properties = MapProperties(isMyLocationEnabled = permissionState.status.isGranted),
            onMapLoaded = {
                isMapLoaded = true
            }) {

            if (isMapLoaded) {
                onGoogleMapDrawn()
            }
        }

        if(isMapLoaded.not()) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)) {
                // PLace Your loading Icon here
            }
        }

    }
}
```

> for calling this function use below code

```
     val positionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
                position = CameraPosition(
                    LatLng(lat,lng),
                    15f,
                    0f,
                    0f
                )
            }

  DrawGoogleMap(positionState = positionState) {
  }
```